# Regular expression for an SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, ssms-2014

I'm looking for a regular expression for the below SQL query.

```
Select * from data where url like '%?%<alphabet>'
```

Where the

> alphabet

can be any alphabet(a-z).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the regular expression supposed to go into the SQL query? Or do you want a regular expression that finds SQL queries in files?

Comment: what is your SQL storage engine?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The SQL standard does not require regular expression support so the functionality differs depending on the database.

Comment: SQL query is just as an example. We need to use it in string also.

Comment: I'm using g mssql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While RegEx is not supported in SQL Server you may try using the pattern matching feature of the LIKE keyword.

[Pattern matching in search conditions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE url LIKE '%[a-z]'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help